# Homebrew failed to link libmpc

Tags: homebrew

After 
`brew install libmpc`
I got an error

```
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link libmpc'
```

Then I run

```
brew doctor
```

and I got

```
Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these: `libmpc`
```

So I run

```
brew link libmpc
```

and I got

```
Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/libmpc/1.0.1/lib/libmpc.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libmpc.dylib may already exist.
/usr/local/lib may not be writable.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean up old homebrew files:

```
brew cleanup
```